# How to logout and kill all the running processes

Tags: arch-linux, x11

Currently i logout by killing Xorg like this:

```bsh
killall Xorg
```

but i want to kill all the processes with it, so it will be like a shallow restart, restarting without physically doing it.

Comment: What exacly do you mean with kill all processes? You probably don't really mean *all* (even PID 1?).

Comment: I'm not sure what will happen if i do that, but ultimately i want to just restart everything, because if i run that command above, it will keep all the processes and opened programs open.

Answer (score 0):

This one liner might help:

```
ps --user $USERNAME | awk 'NR > 1 {print $1}' | xargs -t kill
```

You may run it twice, the second time with `xargs -t kill -SIGKILL`